# Celeryd can't seem to find my Django project’s settings

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, init.d

I'm a celery noob at the moment, but trying to get started.  I'm running Django 1.4 + django-celery + celery 3.0.21 with a redis storage backend.  I can get a worker and celerybeat to run 'manually' via:

`python manage.py celery worker -E -B --loglevel=INFO -n w1.manual`

I want to move this into init-scripts.  So, I've installed the two init scripts supplied by celery.  I can run them as desired and *the scripts* work fine.  However, the worker started by the script is failing. It doesn't appear to be finding my project's settings.  Here's the contents of my configuration file at /etc/default/celeryd:

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/www/www_project_com/"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# Name of the celery config module.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="www-data"
CELERYD_GROUP="www-data"

# Name of the projects settings module
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

my settings files is actually divided into local/production/etc. and the production settings are located here:

```
/var/www/www_project_com/project/settings/production.py
```

I've attempted to change the last line of the config file to be:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings.production"
```

But it seemed to make no difference.

I know that the init scripts are picking up the settings file /etc/default/celery because the process *is* using my custom-defined user and group.

It is clear that the processes are failing because the logs show:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

Which I presume is a default setting.  My Django project is configured to use Redis using the connection string:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
```

As another attempt to sort this out, I've tried setting the last line to:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.production"
```

This results in:

```
[2013-07-19 05:31:48,117: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ImportError('No module named settings',)
```

In the logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE config make sure that the config for CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE is not set.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've made a new file, `celeryconfig.py` placed in the root of my project at `/var/www/www_project_com/celeryconfig.py`, I copied all of my celery-related configuration into this file and retried. No difference at all. =(

Comment: Ah ha! So. Turns out, the solution was to comment out the line `CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="..."`, apparently, this was overriding the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` line. Your comment answer helped me figure this out, so I'd like to give you credit. Can you update your answer to include the language "... or, if you want to use DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=..., comment out the line CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE"? If so, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now! I went ahead and updated the answer.  Now I am curious why it didn't work when you moved the settings into celeryconfig.py and CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE was pointing to the updated config file.

Comment: I'd like to understand that as well.